# Объединить несколько XSD-файлов в один XSD на .NET или через утилиту

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

У меня есть 3 файла xsd, один основной, в нём ссылки на другие xsd-файлы оформлены через <xs:any namespace=urn:....>?

1. Можно ли как-то программно на **.NET** объединить эти **3 xsd-файла в один xsd**?
2. Если нет, может есть хотя бы утилита или что-то типа того, что позволит это сделать вручную?

- ***main.xsd*** -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01">
<xs:import namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" schemaLocation="bah.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="BizData" type="BusinessData"/>
    <xs:complexType name="BusinessApplicationHeader">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" processContents="strict"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="StrictPayload">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:DRAFT6auth.093.001.01" processContents="strict"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BusinessData">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Hdr" type="BusinessApplicationHeader"/>
            <xs:element name="Pyld" type="StrictPayload"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

- ***bah.xsd*** -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01">
    <xs:element name="AppHdr" type="ApplicationHeader"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ApplicationHeader">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">ApplicationHeader</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation source="Definition" xml:lang="EN"></xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    ..........
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

- ***body.xsd*** -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:DRAFT6auth.093.001.01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:DRAFT6auth.093.001.01" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
       .....................
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет, в общем случае этого сделать нельзя.

Обратите внимание: каждый файл задаёт схему ровно для одного пространства имён. У вас три файла, которые используют три разных пространства имён. И эти три пространства имён вы в один файл никак не запихнёте.

Однако, вот что вы можете сделать:

1. во-первых, вы можете добавить в ваш main.xsd явный импорт файла body.xsd и его схемы при помощи любого редактора (включая Блокнот) по аналогии с уже имеющимся импортом файла bah.xsd - большинству программ такового указания более чем хватит чтобы "подхватить" схему;
2. во-вторых, вы можете выложить дополнительные схемы на сетевой ресурс и исправить атрибут schemaLocation в импортах так, чтобы он указывал на него - это может помочь с кривыми программами которые не умеют работать с несколькими файлами, но используют библиотеки которые это всё же умеют (однако это может поломать более умные программы);
3. если ограничение на один файл - строгое, но читающая схему программа - ваша - просто положите все три файла в zip-архив, и читайте его через [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0)